# Is length and this->length are same in this code in c++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this

I have an overloaded operator:

```
rectangletype rectangletype::operator+(const rectangletype& rect) const
{
    rectangletype temprect;
    temprect.length = length + rect.length;
    return temprect;
}
```

And this is the main:

```
int main()
{
    rectangletype r1(23);
    rectangletype r2(27);
    rectangletype r3 = r1 + r2;
    r3.print();
}
```

In the overloaded operator function, when I use this->length istead of length, it gives the same result, but does it work like same?

Comment: You don't have to be implicit and use `this->`. Yes it works the same in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you override an operator, the `this` keyword refers to the object on the left side of the operator in the statement. In the overload function, you can explicitly use `this->`, but it is implied and therefore not necessary.

Comment: It's worth noting that this applies to any member function, not just operator overrides.